# CSS Background styling of end of line

Tags: html, css

I'm working on highlighting search results in text (code snippets)

Currently the found results are being stuffed into a `span` tag with background styling which works... OK.

It looks a little weird when you have empty lines.

```css
span.result {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<pre>
 This is a <span class='result'>chunk of code;

 that has some</span> funny highlighting many lines;
<pre>
```

Is it possible to style the inline `span` in such a way that EOL's background colour extends to the right edge of the parent block (`pre`)?

In the example above

1. The highlight should start mid-line and extend all the way to the right edge
2. The second line should be completely highlighted
3. The third line's highlighting should end mid-line.

Comment: Do you a screenshot of the desired end result?

Comment: @Ori Drori, Thank-you for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is applicable in your case, but one thing you could do is give your whole pre element a blue background color, and then put a span around the parts that should remain white.

```css
pre {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  max-width: min-content;
}

.other {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<span class="other">This is a </span><span class='result'>chunk of code;

that has some</span><span class="other"> funny highlighting many lines</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: That solution is so simple, and elegant (aka obvious in hindsight), my jaw dropped when I read it. Unfortunately, I'm actually doing multiple sections in different colors.... I think I may have to accept your answer just because it's *exactly* what I described